# Unresolved class 'MainActivity'

Tags: android, xml, flutter, mobile

I tried various ways to solve this problem but nothing worked for me.
Here is place where I have errors in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 android:label="cartoon_magic"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

```
Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
Unresolved class 'MainActivity'
Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here
Attribute android:theme is not allowed here
Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here
Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here
```

I guess there is a problem with import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.cartoon_magic

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Here is structure of project:

[image: project structure]

I am completely confused and do not know in which direction to look for the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A good `AndroidManifest.xml` file looks like so

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package.name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!--Your permissions-->

<application
        android:name=".common.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="${appIcon}" <!--Link to your app icon-->
        ...
<!--Activities go here-->
 <activity
            android:name=".view.activity.AgreementDetails"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

</application>    

</manifest>
```

The important things to be noted are whether or not you use the correct values inside the correct tags, for example, the properties in the `<application>` tag won't work inside the `<activity>` tag. Also look around if you have closed all the tags.
You can close the tags in two ways. Look carefully how the different properties are written

```
<activity android:label="xyz" android:orientation="landscape">
// Your intent related parameters here
</activity>
```

Or

```
<activity android:label="xyz" android:orientation="landscape"/> <!--Notice the tag is close inline here-->
```

Comment: I downloaded project from here: 

https://github.com/retroportalstudio/flutter_gallery_storage


And I still have same errors. I think the problem is not with the AndroidManifest.xml itself.